# Need logs on basis of time parameter in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I want to store only those logs which are having execution time less then 20 msecs, there is huge file for this attaching few lines of logs for the same.
Would you please help.

---

---

debug
Log Message:
Message Source: null
Message:
{"name":"splocal_GetQualityData","schema":"dbo","inputParameters":{"1":"628AF1E4-54E4-471E-A5F1-D8C1EF74D7CB","2":"743FB2E8-6D63-4F0B-8E03-79799072F4EE","3":1,"4":false},"outputParameters":null}
{}
Execution Time: 13 msecs
2018-06-14 00:00:20

---

debug
Log Message:
Message Source: null
Message:
30, 2018 4:00:00
AM","IsUserClockedOn":false,"MaterialDefinitionS95Id":"56L1001WC59","LotOPAvailableQty":1.0,"TimeZoneName":"GMT-5","BatchId":null,"LotOPStartTime":"Jan
1, 2100 12:00:00 AM","Sequence":null,"RowNum":1,"ScheduledEndDate":"Jun 21,
2018 4:00:00 AM","SortDate":"May 30, 2018 12:00:00 AM","PriorOpEndTime":"Jun
13, 2018 10:12:15 PM","MaterialLotS95Id":"V220604","LotStatus":"In
Progress","IsSerialized":true},"2":{"LotOperationSegmentResponseId":"41E01DE9-B306-4039-B774-46229E700D5A","LotOPCompleteQty":0.0,"ActiveClockOnCount":0,"OrderPriority":0,"OrderQty":10.0,"LotOPStatus":"Ready","LotSegmentResponseId":"21C238F0-7F52-459C-AC99-394E347E28EB","ShopOrderS95Id":"HIF1100-006NSUPP3","ClockedOnUsers":null,"Operation":"7","ScheduledStartDate":"May
30, 2018 4:00:00
2018 4:00:00 AM","SortDate":"Jun 11, 2018 12:00:00 AM","PriorOpEndTime":"Jun
13, 2018 11:52:00 PM","MaterialLotS95Id":"V240070","LotStatus":"In
Progress","IsSerialized":true}}
Execution Time: 105 msecs
2018-06-14 00:00:21

---

debug
Log Message:
Message Source: null
Message:
{"name":"spLocal_GetOperations_ByOperationId","schema":"dbo","inputParameters":{"1":"88AD5E8A-D63E-4F4B-AC66-CFE039275F73","2":"8A42EB09-1765-49AD-ADA4-5E9614645522","3":"\u003c?xml
16, 2018 4:00:00 AM","SortDate":"Apr 24, 2018 12:00:00
AM","ScheduledStartDate":"Apr 24, 2018 4:00:00
AM","IsUserClockedOn":false,"MaterialLotS95Id":"V170069","LotStatus":"Hold","MaterialDefinitionS95Id":"18L0009WH","IsSerialized":true},"2":{"LotOperationSegmentResponseId":"1BD13FF3-A802-4C59-A23B-0CCDCA6B1149","LotOPAvailableQty":1.0,"LotOPCompleteQty":0.0,"ActiveClockOnCount":0,"OrderPriority":3,"OrderQty":195.0,"LotOPStatus":"Hold","TimeZoneName":"GMT-5","BatchId":null,"ShopOrderS95Id":"HSR200065230L","ClockedOnUsers":null,"Operation":"30","Sequence":null,"ScheduledEndDate":"Jan
31, 2018 5:00:00 AM","SortDate":"Jan 8, 2018 12:00:00
AM","ScheduledStartDate":"Jan 8, 2018 5:00:00
AM","ScheduledStartDate":"Jun 4, 2018 4:00:00
AM","IsUserClockedOn":false,"MaterialLotS95Id":"V230217","LotStatus":"In
Progress","MaterialDefinitionS95Id":"58L105WC60","IsSerialized":true}}
Execution Time: 22 msecs
2018-06-14 00:00:21

---

Comment: cat test.txt | tr "\n" "#"| sed "s|#Execution Time: |,|g" |sed "s|msecs#|msecs,|g"|sed 's|#\*|\n\*|g'|awk -F, '{if($(NF -1) < 20) print $0}'|tr "#" "\n"|sed "s|msecs,|msecs\n|g"|sed "s|},|}\n|g"

Comment: I used this command but it won't work for more then 100 msecs apart from that it worked

Comment: Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below script:

```
#!/bin/bash #You can get bash path using 'which bash' command

IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat logFile` #You can use while in place of for, while provides better performance
do
    execTime=`echo $i|grep "Execution Time:" | sed  's/^.*: //' | awk '{print $1}'`
    limitTime=20
    if [ "$execTime" -lt "$limitTime" ] #executionTime less than 20ms
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```